# Google Maps API Sea Routes

Tags: google-maps-api-3

i searched enough and didn't find any way to remove the sea routes from a port to another, what featureType should i use on map options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to remove ferry lines; are those your concern?

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  }
]
```

It also removes other "transit lines" on the ground. which may be undesirable.