# Where to get the data (i.e., geolocations) of the shipping routes shown on Google map?

Tags: google-maps

Any ideas about that? it's should be international standards. I've been tried hard on searching for the data, but i cannot find out any place to download.

Thanks.

Comment: What shipping routes shown on Google Map?

Comment: @geocodezip Sorry, i don't have enough reputation to post images. If you zoom in the Google map to some waters (e.g., Singapore waters), you can see some dotted lines indicating the shipping routes. I'm wondering where to download the geo points on the dotted lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are ferry routes (see the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600279/google-maps-api-sea-routes/12602891#12602891)).  You might be able to get them with the directions service, using [TravelMode.TRANSIT](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#TravelMode).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I find `google.maps.DirectionsRoute object` might help.